# Start the element in a new line

Tags: html, css, vue.js, styling

I want to style the below code in a way that the `.filter-container`s sit next to each other in rows, when a `.filter-container` has a `.header-container` , that  `.filter-container` should start in a new line and the rest of the `.filter-container`s will continue siting next to it in the new line and this goes on.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
        options: [
          {
            Id: 80,
            group: { GroupName: "MatrixDesc" },
            column: { ColumnAlias: "ReviewStatus" },
          },
          { Id: 81, group: { GroupName: "" }, column: { ColumnAlias: "AOI" } },
          {
            Id: 82,
            group: { GroupName: "" },
            column: {
              ColumnAlias: "Location",
            },
          },
          {
            Id: 83,
            group: { GroupName: "Header2" },
            column: { ColumnAlias: "Chemical" },
          },
          {
            Id: 84,
            group: { GroupName: "" },
            column: {
              ColumnAlias: "CollectionDate",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
  
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">  
  <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-end mx-3">
    <div v-for="(fdata, index) in options" :key="index">
      <span v-if="fdata.group != null">
        <div v-if="fdata.group.GroupName" class="header-container">
          <h4>{{ fdata.group.GroupName }}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="Filter-with-header">
          <div class="Filter-info-wrapper">
            <input
              type="text"
              spellcheck="false"
              v-model="fdata.column.ColumnAlias"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Desired layout:

[image: Desired layout]

Current layout:

[image: Current layout]

Answer (score 0):

Can the options data be tweaked?  It would make more sense for everything that should be grouped together to have the same group name.  Then a computed property can get an array of unique group names. Following that, render each unique group with v-for, then inside that render all the options that match that group name with another v-for.

```html
<div id="app">  
  <div v-for="group in uniqueGroups" class="header-container row mx-3">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h4>{{ group }}</h4>
      <div  class="row mx-0 my-2">
        <div v-for="(fdata, index) in options" :key="index">
          <template v-if="fdata.group != null && fdata.group.GroupName === group">
            <div class="Filter-with-header">
              <div class="Filter-info-wrapper">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  spellcheck="false"
                  v-model="fdata.column.ColumnAlias"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </template>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    options: [
      {
        Id: 80,
        group: { GroupName: "MatrixDesc" },
        column: { ColumnAlias: "ReviewStatus" },
      },
      { 
        Id: 81, 
        group: { GroupName: "MatrixDesc" }, 
        column: { ColumnAlias: "AOI" }
      },
      {
        Id: 82,
        group: { GroupName: "MatrixDesc" },
        column: { ColumnAlias: "Location" },
      },
      {
        Id: 83,
        group: { GroupName: "Header2" },
        column: { ColumnAlias: "Chemical" },
      },
      {
        Id: 84,
        group: { GroupName: "Header2" },
        column: { ColumnAlias: "CollectionDate" },
      },
    ],
  },
  computed: {
    uniqueGroups() {
      return [...new Set(this.options.map(o => o.group.GroupName))]
    }
  }
})
```

[example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7be2640a/1/)